# Free energy surface plotting

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, physics

Please feel free to move this to a different board if it doesn't fit the best here.

I am working on trying to plot the free energy surface of ferroelectric materials, similar to the image below. Each point in a given coordinate space is calculated for a energy value and then those energy values can be used to generate a 3D surface. So for example, at $(x, y, z) == (0.5, 0.5 ,0.5)$ you may generate an energy $E$. However, I haven't been able to find a way either through Mathematica or Python to generate surfaces such as the ones you see below.

I have considered changing the $(X, Y, Z)$ coordinate system into spherical coordinates, however, it would leave out the energy *E* which is used to depict the actual surface. Another idea is to potentially evaluate the function at different slices of the $Z$ coordinate and build up a plot from that, because then I could find an azimuth angle from the origin and use the energy value calculated as a radius. However, the problem I run into there, especially with regard to Python, is stacking up the individual slices doesn't work as intended.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am well-versed in Python and decent in Mathematica (which from my knowledge is more powerful from a visualization standpoint). Whether you want to share code or just provide insight is fine.

[image: Free Energy Surface Plots]

**Edit 1**

For those curious of the free energy equation it can be seen below.

$\qquad f(X,Y,Z) = \\ 
\qquad\quad   \alpha_1 (X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2) + \alpha_{11} (X^4 + Y^4 + Z^4) + \\ 
\qquad\quad \alpha_{12} (X^2 Y^2 + X^2 Z^2 + Y^2 + Z^2) + \alpha_{111} (X^6 + Y^6 + Z^6) + \\ 
\qquad\quad \alpha_{112} (X^4 (Y^2 + Z^2) + Y^4 (X^2 + Z^2) + Z^4 (X^2 + Z^2)) + \alpha_{123} (X^2 Y^2 Z^2)$

The different $ \alpha_{i} $ coefficients are dependent on material properties and irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: You forgot to publish the energy surface equation.

Comment: Seems like you were looking for `ContouPlot3D` and its option `ColorFunction`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Oh, I apologize. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: What $\alpha _i$ are assumed for ferroelectric materials?

Comment: I haven't tried this in mathematica yet, but I do have it working in python (I read up on what ContourPlot3D does and find some ways to mimic it in Python)

@AlexTrounev To answer your question about what the coeficients. They are dependent on the material being studied and may or may not be dependent on temperature and pressure as well.

Comment: @JacobZorn To build a surface, you need to know the numerical values of the coefficients. Publish the $\alpha _I$ numbers you use on Python. Or give a link to the article from which you took the picture.